# Mouse access to contact Quick Search

Tags: core

Since an update a while ago, the behavior of the Quick Search field has changed: It is no longer possible to edit/mark the field content by double-clicking the mouse. Instead, we have to backspace to remove an input, and there is no way to quickly delete the whole content.

The loss of time is not huge, but a little annoying. Is there perhaps a setting that we can change it to make it work again?

Comment: The quick search box is still a text input and when I try it on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard, I'm able to edit/mark the field content with mouse click correctly. Can you maybe paste the screenshot of what looks wrong on your end?

Comment: Interesting I see the same thing as Detlev. Double-clicking or even single clicking just does nothing, and I can't drag the mouse across the text. But I can press shift-home or shift-end or ctrl-a to quickly select all. Maybe a browser difference or windows/mac difference? I was using firefox on windows.

Comment: YES! A browser issue:
With Firefox (68.0.1 on Linus) this bug is present, while e.g. Chromium (76) is working fine.

However, this should be investigated and solved...

Comment: FWIW, with Firefox 70 on macOS, I think I experience the same issue - I click into the box and type fine, but using the pointer to move/edit/select is wonky.

Comment: I filed a Civi bug report @ https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1525